# Swift: change uilabel text from another class

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

> Index.swift

```
let boxClass = SelectBox()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    reloadData()
    boxClass.openSelector(defValue: myView)
}

func reloadData(){
    self.nowOnline.text = "Waiting ..." 
    countOnline = 2 
}
```

This code work fine.

But if i want change value from another class, not work

> SelectBox.swift

```
class SelectBox {
    internal func openSelector(myView:UIView){
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleClick(sender:))))
    }
}

@objc func handleClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    reloadData()
}
```

Code story:

1- I go to index app

2- `reloadData()` work fine

3- I click on `myView` and `reloadData()` call again

4- app crashed, because `nowOnline` return `nil`

Comment: You need an instance of class you have in index.Swift and call the `reloadData()` with that instance.

Comment: index class object need to be creatyed within the SelectBox class  and with that object you have to call reloadData

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Can you explain more? i am beginner

Comment: @ManuRaphy Can you send me codes ? thank you

Comment: Check my answer. What is the name of the viewController in Index.swift? And where is the Box initialization done?

Comment: @ComputerIm already added

Comment: @RakeshaShastri no it did not

Answer (score 1):

```
class SelectBox {
   let indexObj = index()
    internal func openSelector(myView:UIView){
        myView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:    #selector(handleClick(sender:))))
    }

@objc func handleClick(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    indexObj.reloadData()
  }
}
```

Comment: How will this work if you create a new instance of the index object? You need the same older instance.

Comment: just an illustration on how things done. for real scenario you have to use the delegate pattern

Comment: How does this show that he has to use the delegate pattern?